# displaying data in android app retrieved from database

Tags: android

I want to display data which is retrieved from any database. which view is best grid view or table . can we display data in the grid view like table format.
 Please suggest me any one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u can use list view,grid view and also u can use view group for this purpose...i recommend listview because it is lighter compared to viewgroup.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ListView` which can contain no. of columns within each row.

Data can be populated by using `ArrayAdapter` or `Custom Adapter` which extends `BaseAdapter`.

You may refer to [this](http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.in/2011/09/using-sqlite-to-populate-listview-in.html) on SO.